# Can I make an item look like it has different enchantments than it actually does?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want a Riptide X trident, but for secrecy purposes, I want it to only look like it is a Riptide III trident.

How can I use Minecraft commands to make an item display different enchantments than it actually has?

Comment: There is no visual difference between a Riptide X trident and a Riptide III or below trident. The only way for someone to know is if you kill someone with the item or they see you fly 200 blocks into the air with the item.

Comment: @ScythePhantom But it'll display Riptide X on the tooltip, and I believe that OP wants to change that.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I was typing the comment as it was edited. Might have misunderstood it as the question states that clearly now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use the hideFlags nbt tag to hide the enchantments, then you can use a lore tag to show a dummy enchantment.

Note: the item will say it has 4 nbt tags with the advanced tooltips debug feature.

```
/give @s minecraft:trident{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:riptide",lvl:10}],HideFlags:1,display:{Lore:["{\"text\":\"Riptide III\",\"color\":\"gray\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"]}} 1
```